# Bezier curve, question for the new control point

Tags: bezier

For a Bezier curve I know the P0,P1 and the
control point P2. (and I can calculate the Q0)

I want to find for a new curve, with Q1(t=0,25) == Q0(t=0,25),
P0==Q0(t=0.25) and P1==Q0(t=0.75),
the new control point P2.

I re-edit my initial post. I've added a picture.
In the picture the blue and red dots are my initial P0 and P1 points and the green dot is the initial control point P2.

Now, I want to find the new control point P2' if I now the purple points P1' and P2'.

In essence I want to draw 2 new curves,
a) from red point to first purple point and
b) from blue point to the second purple point
[image]

Any idea?

Comment: What are P0, P1, Q0, and Q1? Because while a familiarity with curves will have anyone know that P stans for point, Q is not an established letter other than to represent "a quadratic curve in SVG context", which doesn't appear to be the case here, so it has no established meaning. And remember not to tell "me", [update your post](/help/how-to-ask) to clarify that (either in text or with a well-labelled picture) to tell "everyone".

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit convoluted but I will give it a shot. To me it seems that OP wants the control points of the segment of the original curve from the parameter value *t* = 0.25 up to the parameter value *t*=0.75. This can be achieved using [De Casteljau's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm) twice. Since I haven't found a step-by-step version for quadratic curves on SO, I made one.

Step 0: Take your three control points (note that I name them in a more usual order but I use OP's colour scheme).
[image: Starting point of De Casteljau's algorithm]

Step 1: Use De Casteljau's algorithm for *t*=0.25. This means that

- *P*_01 = 0.25 * *P*_0 + (1 - 0.25) * *P*_1,
- *P*_12 = 0.25 * *P*_1 + (1 - 0.25) * *P*_2 and
- *P*_012 = 0.25 * *P*_01 + (1 - 0.25) * *P*_12.

Note the purple colour signifying that my *P*_012 corresponds to the left of OP's purple points.
[image: First run of De Casteljau's algorithm]

Step 2: Rename things to simplify writing the second run of the algorithm.
[image: Renaming before the second run of De Casteljau's algorithm]

Step 3: Use De Casteljau's algorithm for the second time. But be careful: the parameter value *t*=0.75 of the original curve corresponds to the parameter value *t*=2/3 of what is left from it. This means that

- *P'*_01 = 2/3 * *P'*_0 + (1 - 2/3) * *P'*_1,
- *P'*_12 = 2/3 * *P'*_1 + (1 - 2/3) * *P'*_2 and
- *P'*_012 = 2/3 * *P'*_01 + (1 - 2/3) * *P'*_12.

[image: Second run of De Casteljau's algorithm]

Step 4: Rename things again and pick up the results:

- *P''*_0 is the left of OP's purple points,
- *P''*_1 is the green point OP is looking for and
- *P''*_2 is the right of OP's purple points.

[image: Results]